# Controlling the degree of parallelism and making sure the operation finished

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I have the following code which tries to process an array of endpoints in parallel:

```
callApiEndpoint(endpoint: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient
    .get<any>(endpoint)
    .pipe(
      tap(
        data =>
          console.log(`calling ${endpoint} returned ${JSON.stringify(data)}`),
        catchError(ApiCallerComponent.handleError)
      )
    );
}

getEndpointsToProcess(): string[] {
  const result = [];

  this.idsToProcess.forEach(element => {
    result.push(this.getEndpoint(element));
  });

  return result;
}

processRequests() {
  const endpoints = this.getEndpointsToProcess();

  forkJoin(endpoints.map(uri => <Observable<any>>this.callApiEndpoint(uri)))
    .pipe(concatAll())
    .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
}
```

How would I be able to control the degree of parallel requests made to the API server? In addition, how would I be able to say all the requests have finished irrespective of their outcomes?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/observable/forkJoinConcurrent.ts